# Is there any Agent Development framework for Objective-C or C++?

Tags: agent, agents

Like [JADe](http://jade.tilab.com/), but not for Java. Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about http://www.mobilec.org/?

Answer (score 0):

If it's still actual, try these frameworks: [Relacy](https://sourceforge.net/projects/relacy/?source=navbar), [SObjectizer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sobjectizer/?source=directory), CAF (http://www.actor-framework.org/). And see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model#Actor_libraries_and_frameworks

Answer (score 0):

There is a msdn library but it doesn't have FIPA functionality like Contract net communication and directory facilitator.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492627.aspx

There was a project called CAPNET where FIPA compliant agents where developed for MSDN but this was discontinued and all the documentation is in Spanish.

Goodluck, also look at F#.